# Add Layered Navigation in custom module - Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, layered-navigation

I want to add layered navigation block in custom module page and filter custom product collection.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

here it is your solution.
[click here : shop_by_brand in layered navigation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139219/how-to-add-custom-attribute-shop-by-brand-filter-in-layered-navigation-witho)

create script for that attribute as system attribute and give options to them and select that option values for product which stores in

```
catalog_product_entity_varchar
```

above magento table.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to add layered navigation in custom page not want to add attribute in layered navigation