# How to add custom attribute [ shop_by_brand ] filter in layered navigation without using admin in Magento 2.1 ?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layered-navigation

I want to add shop_by_brand attribute in layered navigation without using backend admin.
I have created this attribute using schema:-

```
 $eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'shop_by_brand',
        [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Shop by Brand',
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => 0,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
```

Comment: Please expand your post with your actual question. What result were you expecting? What result did you get? Did you run into any error messages? Etc.

Answer (score -1):

create observer on brand creation and add options to your attribute :

```
$brand = $observer->getEvent()->getBrand();
    $option_id = "";

    $data = [];
    $attribute_arr = [$brand['brand_id'] => $brand['brand_title']];
    $optionTable = $this->setup->getTable('eav_attribute_option');
    $attributeInfo=$this->_attributeFactory->getCollection()
           ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code',['eq'=>"shop_by_brand"])
           ->getFirstItem();

    $attribute_id = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();

    $eavAttribute = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Config');

    $option=array();
    $option['attribute_id'] = $attributeInfo->getAttributeId();

    $storeManager = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $stores = $storeManager->getStores();
    $storeArray[0] = "All Store Views";       

    foreach ($stores  as $store) {
        $storeArray[$store->getId()] = $store->getName();
    }


    if (empty($brand['optionId'])) {
        foreach($attribute_arr as $key => $value){
            $option['value'][$value][0]=$value;
                foreach($storeArray as $storeKey => $store){
                    $option['value'][$value][$storeKey] = $value;
                }                
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach($attribute_arr as $key => $value){
                foreach($storeArray as $storeKey => $store){
                    $option['value'][$brand['optionId']][$storeKey] = $value;
                }                
        }
    }

    $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create();
    $eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);

    if (empty($brand['optionId'])) {

       /** @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $attribute */
        $attribute = $eavAttribute->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'shop_by_brand');

        $alloptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();


        foreach ($alloptions as $key => $optiontext) {            
            if($optiontext['label']==$brand['oldtext'])
            {
                $option_id = $optiontext['value'];
            }
            continue;
        }

        $rowData = $this->_objectManager->create('<vendor>\<your_module>\Model\Brand');
        $rowData->load($brand['brand_id']);

        $rowData->setOptionId($option_id);        

        $rowData->save();
     }
     else
    {
        $option_id = $brand['optionId'];
    }
```

you have to select option values either from admin as :
[image]

or you need to select product attribute below your option code as below :

```
if (isset($_POST['products'])) 
     {
        $products = explode('&', $_POST['products']);



            foreach ($products as $key => $productIds) {


                $productdata =  $this->_productloader->create()->load($productIds);

                $valuesId = $option_id;

                $oldIds = explode(',', $productdata->getData("shop_by_brand"));


                if(!in_array($valuesId, $oldIds))
                {

                    $valuesId .= "," .  $productdata->getData("shop_by_brand");

                    $valuesIds = explode(",", $valuesId);
                    $productdata->setStoreId(0);
                    $productdata->setData("shop_by_brand", $valuesIds);

                    $productdata->save();
                }

            }
    }
```

here is your attribute in layered navigation :

[image]

Thanks :)